# "while"/"for" loop in kernel causing CUDA out of memory error?

Tags: c++, loops, memory, cuda

If I change the while loop (see kernel below, it's a monstrous loop, you can't miss it) to iterate only once, it uses  a negligible amount of GPU memory. However, when the loop is allowed to iterate 50,000 times as shown below, the GPU instantly takes on 2.5 GB. The problem persists even when using a "for" loop. Can someone please offer an explanation and perhaps a solution to prevent the kernel from using so much memory? This behavior is highly unusual, IMO. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "curand.h"
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <time.h>

    __global__ void myKern(const float *transMatrix, float *masterForces, const double *rands, const int r_max)
    {


    const int iterationsx = 50000;
    const int RUsizex = 26;

    int threadsPerBlock = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;
    int blockId = blockIdx.x + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x);
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x); 
    int globalIdx = (blockId * threadsPerBlock) + threadId;

    int RU[RUsizex] = {0};

    int index = 0;
    float r = 0.0;
    double temp = 0;

    float forces[iterationsx] = {0.0};
    int left[RUsizex - 2] = {0};
    int right[RUsizex - 2] = {0};

    curandState s;
    curand_init (rands[globalIdx] , 0, 0, &s);

    int i= 0;

    while( i < iterationsx)
    {

            for(int k = 0; k < RUsizex - 2; k++)
            {
            left[k] = RU[k];
            right[k] = RU[k+2];
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < RUsizex -2; j++)
            {

                r = curand_uniform(&s);



                index =  ((((left[j] * dimen2 + right[j]) * dimen3  + RU[j +1 ]) * dimen4) * dimen5) ;



                RU[j + 1]= (RU[j + 1]) + ( r < transMatrix[index]) * (transMatrix[index + 1]) +
                    (! (r < transMatrix[index])) * ( r < transMatrix[index + 2]) * (transMatrix[index + 3]) +
                    (! ( r < transMatrix[index + 2])) * (r < transMatrix[index + 4]) * (transMatrix[index + 5]) ;



            }


            for(int z = 1; z < RUsizex - 1; z++)
            {
                temp = temp + (RU[z] ==4) + (RU[z] ==5);

            }

            forces[i] = temp/(24.0);
            temp = 0.0;
    i++;
    }


    for(int y = 0; y < iterationsx; y++)
    {
        masterForces[globalIdx + (r_max * y)] = forces[y]; 
    }





    }
```

Comment: `masterForces[globalIdx + (r_max * y)] = forces[y];` where `y` is looping till `iterationsx`. I am guessing you allocate memory for masterForces proportional to `iterationsx`?

Comment: @pradhan yes that is true. Do you think the issue is with this loop?

Comment: The memory allocation for `masterForces` being proportional to `iterationsx` would explain why you see the GPU mem consumption increase. To confirm, you could check that the usage grows linearly - try, say `iterationsx=1000` and `iterationsx=5000` and see how the usage grows.

Comment: Yes that is true and I tested this exact thing and saw linear memory consumption. But the thing is, masterForces is only 50000 x 1 large for a kernel with one thread (globalIdx never gets bigger than 0 and r_max =1). So multiply this by 4 bytes and you get the expected size requirement. This value is only .19 MB. Far less than 2.5 GB that gets consumed.

Comment: The variable float forces[iterationsx] is a stack variable in a global function. This requires a stack reservation of > 200,000B per thread. The CUDA driver must allocate a local memory allocation based upon the maximum resident threads using the formula SmCount * MaxTheadsPerSm * (LocalMemoryPerThread + StackPerThread). For a full GK110 this would be 15 * 2048 * ~51KiB = 1.5 GiB.

Comment: @GregSmith: That is a perfect answer, if you would care to add it as one.

Comment: @Greg Smith Oh wow that's interesting, I've never read anything about this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but my options should be pretty limited on this one. I think my only option is to remove is remove the float [ ] forces array and write results into masterForces immediately as they become available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable float forces[iterationsx] is a stack variable in a global function. This requires a stack reservation of > 200,000B per thread. The CUDA driver must allocate a local memory allocation based upon the maximum resident threads using the formula SmCount * MaxTheadsPerSm * (LocalMemoryPerThread + StackPerThread). For a full GK110 this would be 15 * 2048 * ~51KiB = 1.5 GiB.